# Task Parallel Library sequential access in .net

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I am writing a component that is displaying the download status of my files. There is an application that access the method of my component and pass the parameter which further contains the information that I need to display on the screen.

So that service access my method very very frequently as it need to give me information for lots of files(which are currently in downloading queue)

```
 private void ProcessMessage(MessageOptions options)
  {
        Task t= Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>
        {
           //update data row using options object
        });    

        Task t1 = t.ContinueWith((continution) =>
               {
                 //here goes the code to update the MainUI   
               }
            ,TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
        }
```

So this does everything I need and up to now I haven't face any practical issue with this approach. 
But there is a potential problem with this method. As this method is continuing to be called this thing could happen

> Call 1 options.FileName="File 1"
>   options.DataTransferred="3 mb"
>
> Call 2 options.FileName="File 2"
>   options.DataTransferred="6 mb"
>
> Call 3 options.FileName="File 1"
>   options.DataTransferred="6 mb"

and so on. And everytime this method gets called a new Task has been initialized and when task is completed it updates the MainUI with the information.

**Problem**

There is no guarantee which task is going to complete first. It is possible that Call3 completed first and display the information that file 1 is downloaded 6 mb and then the Call1 completed and update the information that file 1 is downloaded 3 mb, which definitely is not acceptable.

I want to assure that Task 1 must be finished before Task 3 as both these tasks got the information of File 1.

Thanks

Comment: @svick I've mentioned in the question that it has not failed yet. But I don't see any reason that I wont fail in the future. Task could complete in any sequence and thus could cause the issue.

Comment: Does MessageOptions contain just one message or multiple?

Comment: @Slugart One message at a time

Comment: "There is some windows service that access the method of my application"  - does the client call the server or the other way around?  If it's the client what thread does this happen on?

Comment: @Slugart Sorry for the confusion, I've updated the question.

Comment: I believe if you go to NuGet MS has a .NET 4 Parallel Extensions Extras were there is a task scheduler for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

If you can modify the server and add a version number to the message being sent you can subsequently discard any messages whose version is smaller than the last last version received for that file.

You can also add the version number on the client before updating the data row as long as the messages arrive at ProcessMessage in the correct order.

Comment: That seems like a hack. Even if I somehow modify the server this time there is no guarantee I could do it the next time I face this issue.

Comment: Yeah it seems doable. I need to test it though.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you want your tasks to run independent but you want the continuations to run in sequence regardless of when the tasks are complete.

I would use a concurrent queue like this:

```
private ConcurrentQueue<Task<MessageOptions>> _tasks = new ConcurrentQueue<Task<MessageOptions>>();

private void ProcessMessage(MessageOptions options)
{
    var t= Task<MessageOptions>.Factory.StartNew(()=>
    {
       //update data row using options object
       return options;
    });    

    _tasks.Enqueue(t);

    Task t1 = t.ContinueWith(_ =>
    {
        // everytime a task finishes, update the UI for all completed tasks from the start of the queue
        Task<MessageOptions> firstInQueue;

        while (_tasks.TryPeek(out firstInQueue) &&
               firstInQueue.IsCompleted)
        {
            // this alwys runs in the same thread we can be sure the item is still in the queue
            _tasks.TryDequeue(out firstInQueue);

            var taskOptions = firstInQueue.Result;
            //here goes the code to update the MainUI
        }
    }
    ,TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
 }
```